# how can we back up in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, backup

I need the menus that help me to back up in sql server 2008?
thanks

Comment: Menus?  You mean from in Management Studio?

Comment: I mean the please write like tools> Options>...

Answer (score 3):

to backup a database? Right click on the database, click on `tasks` and then `backup`

[image]

Or in T-SQL

```
BACKUP DATABASE YourDatabase TO  DISK = N'C:\Backup\YourDatabase.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'Full Database Backup', 
SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find this MSDN page helpful:

[How to: Back Up a Database (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To backup a database:

```
USE master
GO
BACKUP DATABASE MyDataBase TO DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLExpress\MSSQL\Backup\MyDataBase.bak'
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'MyDataBase Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD
GO
```

To restore:

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE DATABASE MyDataBase FROM DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLExpress\MSSQL\Backup\MyDataBase.bak'
WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE

-- use with next if file names were changed
,MOVE 'MyDataBase' TO
 N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLExpress\MSSQL\Data\MyDataBase.mdf'
,MOVE 'MyDataBase_log' TO
 N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLExpress\MSSQL\Data\MyDataBase.log.ldf'
GO
```